# Insert char from string into list in one line

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'm after a way to reduce the following code down to one line, I assume through list comprehension.

```
string = raw_input("String: ")
stringlist = []
for char in string:
    stringlist.insert(0, char)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you basically want to reverse the string and create a list from its reversed version:

```
stringlist = list(reversed(raw_input("String: ")))
```

The following is even shorter, but probably a bit harder to read:

```
stringlist = list(raw_input("String: ")[::-1])
```

This code uses [extended slices](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

Comment: Too right, had no idea that `reversed` existed! Fascinating how easily excessive amount of code can be cut down.